# Infinite try-catch blocks to generate an xml with Jaxb?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, try-catch

I ended up into this situation:

```
try {

    // Conversion to xml with Jaxb

} catch (JAXBException e) {
    try {

        // Produce error xml

    } catch (JAXBException e) {

        // Nested catches to infinite?

    }       
}
```

In other words, I have to return to the user an xml, both in case of error or success. However in case of error, the generation of an XML using Jaxb can generate a further exception. But... I cannot nest an other try-catch in every catch, or I need to nest infinite times a try-catch into a catch block. How do I get out of this?

Answer (score 1):

At some point you need to do something different.  If somehow JAXB failed to produce the error XML you needed to return error XML you could return a hard coded XML message.